# Library call failed c++ dll

Tags: c++, vim, dll

vim docs state that I've got to use C calling conventions for all my functions.
This in mind I wrote a bare minimum dll just to see if everything is ok.

```
#include <string>

std::string _declspec(dllexport) Meow() {
    std::string Meow = "Meow!";
    return Meow;
}
```

For compiling I wrote a makefile

```
test.dll: test.cpp
cl /LD test.cpp
clean: 
    del *.obj
    del *.dll
    del *.exp
    del *.lib
```

Compiled without any issues and copied the dll into my vim directory.
In my understanding calling the function via

```
:call libcall("test.dll","Meow",0)<cr>
```

should work. But I keep getting Error 364: Library call failed for "Meow()".
Changing the .dll name inside libcall to something that doesnt exist results in the same error, thus I came to the conclusion something is wrong with my dll.
But then again my dll is compiled without any problems, 
which leaves me puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two problems with your code:

- In C++ names typically get mangled when exported so your `Meow` function will become something like `?Meow@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ`.
- [Vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html) seem to state that function called with `libcall` must match some rather restrictive conditions:

> The function must take exactly one parameter, either a character pointer or a long integer, and must return a character pointer or NULL. The character pointer returned must point to memory that will remain valid after the function has returned (e.g. in static data in the DLL).

Comment: Oooohhh, I see changed the return type to a character pointer and added extern "C" to prevent the name mangling and it worked. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix your example:

```
extern "C"
{  
    static char null_terminated_string[2048];
    char* _declspec(dllexport) Meow(char *arg) 
    {
        strncpy(null_terminated_string, arg, std::min(sizeof(null_terminated_string), strlen(arg));
        return null_terminated_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `extern "C"`?